# Migrating Heroku Project Into Another Programming Language

Tags: heroku

I have a PHP project in my Heroku. It is a LINE Chatbot app. I want to change the code into Go. So, is it possible to 'overwrite' the existing PHP code or should I start a different project?

I've googled this kind of thing but I found zero reference regarding changing programming language in heroku projects.

I tried pushing .go script but I cannot run it with "go run" command. I wanted to pull go-getting-start from heroku, place it in the same directory as my local and push it into heroku but I was too scared.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to create the application image and runtime from your sourcecode.

The buildpack to use it finds via `detect` scripts, which mostly just check the existance of certain files (see the ones for [PHP](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/detect) or [Go](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/detect).

So when you push the commit to heroku which does the switch from PHP to Go, Heroku will just use the new buildpack for the build.

You also can [set the used buildpack manually](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application) or run [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) (for example add `node.js` to compile static assets).